# WPF Combobox display only SOME items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a WPF app(with MVVM) and in this I have a combobox which binds to a table in my database and displays the values, this works just fine.

However, now I want to make a new combobox and bind it to the same table, but now I only want it to display SOME of the values. Is there a simple way to do this?

The table has has four entries but I only want to show 3 of them in this new combobox.

I know I could just make a new table in the database to bind to, but I might have to use several of these comboboxes(with different values) and I'd rather not go through all that bother if I can avoid it.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox   
            Name="cmComp"
            MinWidth="150"
            Margin="12 0 0 12"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedComponentLookup}"
            DisplayMemberPath="ComponentChoice"
            SelectedValuePath="ComponentChoice"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ComponentChosen}">
</ComboBox>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
private IEnumerable<ComponentLookupDto> _selectedComponentLookup;
    public IEnumerable<ComponentLookupDto> SelectedComponentLookup
    {
        get { return _selectedComponentLookup; }
        set
        {
            _selectedComponentLookup = value;
        }
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class ComponentLookupDto
{
    public int ComponentLookupId { get; set; }
    public string ComponentChoice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I achieve this is that I filter out the items I don't want to display in the getter for the property to which I bind my ItemsSource. :

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding SelectedComponentLookupOther} ... />
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<ComponentLookupDto> SelectedComponentLookupOther
{
    get { return _selectedComponentLookup.Where(c => c.SomeProperty == "however you want to pick it out"); }
}
```